# I'm not able to understand this "or" conditions when i am writing 0 or 3 it is returning 3 and also when i am writing 3 and 0 same condition printed

Tags: python

I'm not able to understand these `or` conditions. When I write `0 or 3` it is returning `3` and also when I write `3 and 0` the same conditions are printed but not in other cases. Why?

```
print(3 or 0)
print(0 or 3)
print(3 or 10)
print(10 or 3)
```

Comment: It's 3 or 0 in the third line*

Comment: 0 is "falsy", all other numeric values are "truthy".  `or` returns the first "truthy" operand.

Comment: oh, do it means that every time if associated with 0 I'll get true value and rather the one which is or with?